# How to add items between RadioButtonList?

Tags: asp.net

We have a list that is getting generated server side, then using `<asp:RadioButtonList...` to display it.

How ever, how would we add some HTML after one of the items?

The idea is that if one of them is generated, there are some 'sub' radio buttons that get generated.

Thanks

**ASP.NET:**

```
private void PopulateFollowUpRadioButtons(Order order)
        {
            //Based on the options selected while creating the order template populate the radio button list.
            if (order.OrderTemplate.fur01Visible)
                FolloupRadioButtonList.Items.Add(new ListItem(order.OrderTemplate.fur01Label, "1"));
            if (order.OrderTemplate.fur02Visible)
                FolloupRadioButtonList.Items.Add(new ListItem(order.OrderTemplate.fur02Label, "2"));
            if (order.OrderTemplate.fur03Visible)
                FolloupRadioButtonList.Items.Add(new ListItem(order.OrderTemplate.fur03Label, "3"));


            //If follow up option is already selected then select the option in the Follow Up Radio button control 
            if (order.FollowUpRoleId != null)
                FolloupRadioButtonList.SelectedValue = order.FollowUpRoleId.Value.ToString();
        }


<asp:RadioButtonList ID="FolloupRadioButtonList" CssClass="black" ForeColor="Black"  runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Paste what you have so far.

Comment: @Esa Pasted the code as above.

Comment: If you need hierarchical structure, perhaps RadioButtonList is not the best approach. A tree or a custom user control may be a better option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you *can* assign your HTML directly to `ListItem` text e.g. this code

```
 ListItem li = new ListItem("aaaaa", "aaaaa");
 FolloupRadioButtonList.Items.Add(li);

 li = new ListItem("bbbbb", "bbbbbbb");
 FolloupRadioButtonList.Items.Add(li);

 li.Text += @"<table style='padding-left:50px'>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id='ChildList_0' type='radio' name='ChildList' value='zzzzzzz' /><label for='ChildList_0'>zzzzzzz</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input id='ChildList_1' type='radio' name='ChildList' value='xxxxxxx' /><label for='ChildList_1'>xxxxxx</label></td>
                        </tr>
              </table>";
```

Will produce this list and sublist:

[image: Sub radibuttonlist]

But it won't be truly server-side control. If you need just client-side access to this list - this approach may work for you. Otherwise, as I mentioned in my comments - consider a user control where you can build your own hiearchy out of ASP.NET tables and RadioButtons.

Answer (score 5):

Create your own custom radiobuttonlistcontrol:

```
Namespace Controls
    Public Class MyRadioButtonList
        Inherits RadioButtonList

        Protected Overrides Sub RenderItem(itemType As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemType, repeatIndex As Integer, repeatInfo As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeatInfo, writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
            writer.Write("<div>Extra content</div>")
            MyBase.RenderItem(itemType, repeatIndex, repeatInfo, writer)
        End Sub
    End Class

End Namespace
```

And use it as so.

First register the control to a page, or a user control:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="(projectnamespace)" Namespace="(projectnamespace).Controls" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

And then use the control:

```
<cc1:MyRadioButtonList ID="rdolist" runat="server" />
```

It's a basic radiobuttonlistcontrol in the server side, so just use it as you do now.