# ASP.NET - How to put items of Radiobuttonlist into HTML tag

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I want put items of Radiobuttonlist into `td` tag.

```
<td><asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"></asp:RadioButtonList></td>
```

This is result. This is Matrix, Rows and Column is loaded from database.(RadioButtonList was set datasource).
[image]

I put RadioButtonList into `td` tag: all of items is contained in a cell.
My matrix will be complete when each item contained in a cell.

Have `Itemtemplate` for RadioButtonList like Repeater?

Comment: You can get a clue from this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407934/how-to-add-items-between-radiobuttonlist

Comment: Once the radio button list is loaded you can use jquery wrap function to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own custom radiobuttonlistcontrol:

```
namespace Controls
{
    public class MyRadioButtonList : RadioButtonList
    {

        protected override void RenderItem(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemType itemType, int repeatIndex, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeatInfo repeatInfo, System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.Write("<td>");
            base.RenderItem(itemType, repeatIndex, repeatInfo, writer);
            writer.Write("</td>");
        }
    }

}
```

And use it as so.

First register the control to a page, or a user control:

And then use the control:

It's a basic radiobuttonlistcontrol in the server side, so just use it as you do now.

Comment: It works like a usual radiobuttonlist. Include the control to your page, thats all you have to do.

Comment: Thank you. I'm understand. But i have trouble: `<%@ Register Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Controls" TagPrefix="cc1" %>` I am using Dotnetnuke, it not working???

Comment: Check this out to know how to register an assembly into page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/c76dd5k1(v=vs.85).aspx.
<%@ Register Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web" Namespace="Controls" TagPrefix="cc1" %>. I believe you have put the  code for your control in a class file

Comment: yes, i put in a bottom, class file in code behind of a webform.

Comment: If you got it working pls mark my answer as answer. Thank You!

Comment: I'm coding with dotnetnuke so i can't find App_Code  folder

Comment: Just put the code in a different class in a seperate file.